# How to create UDF in Spark to support custom predicate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe , which has a field of lists datatype that needs to be matched with cross-join, on condition that if any of the elements in the list exists in another list, then the both records should be considered a match.

Example.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf


val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("one", List(1,34,3)), ("one", List(1,2,3)), ("two", List(1))))
          .toDF("word", "count")

val lsEqual = (xs : (List[Int],List[Int])) => xs._1.find(xs._2.contains(_)).nonEmpty
 val equalList = udf(lsEqual)
```

But this gives me the following error

```
val out =  df.joinWith(df,equalList(df("count"),df("count")),"cross")
```

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $anonfun$1 cannot be cast to scala.Function2
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.<init>(ScalaUDF.scala:97)
at org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction.apply(UserDefinedFunction.scala:56)
... 50 elided
```

Is there any other way to create custom predicates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lsEqual` function definition seems to be wrong. `List`, `Seq`, `Array` are treated as `WrappedArray` in *Spark Dataframes*. And you are passing two `columns` to `lsEqual` function, which should have been two variables.

The correct way should be

```
val lsEqual = (xs1 : scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int], xs2 : scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int]) => xs1.find(xs2.contains(_)).nonEmpty
```

which should definitely remove the error you are facing